# How can I access the content of the comment field in zip file. in Typescript

Tags: typescript, zip, metadata

In my program I let my users upload a zip file, from this file I need to extract the content of the comment field of that zip file.
It is a metadata, not a file, every zip file has it.

From what I have seen online all the 3rd parties help create, zip, unzip, and read the content, but I only need to read the metadata of a zip file, that comment field.

I searched a fitting 3rd party for my solution but did not find any.
The object that I get from the input tag is 'FileList' and from that i'm taking the first file, and that file is of the object 'File'. none of those object have access the the comment field. make sense because not all files have this field.

Comment: https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl  This library seems to support extracting comments from the Zip file format.

Comment: I saw that library but could not find something useful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a 3rd party library that helps me access that property: 'unzipit', here's the link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipit?activeTab=readme

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).